# Oracle : unique constraint on 2 columns

Tags: oracle, constraints, unique

I have this table :

```
   ID1 | ID2 |
     1     2
```

I want a unique constraint that forbid the insertion of the couple `(1,2)` but also the couple `(2,1)`.

If i define :

```
  ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT unique_1 UNIQUE (ID1 ,ID2 );
```

I can still insert the couple `(2,1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @a_horse_with_no_name's solution, you can also do this via virtual columns:

```
create table t1 (col1 number,
                 col2 number,
                 col1_col2_least generated always as (least(col1, col2)),
                 col1_col2_greatest generated always as (greatest(col1, col2)));

--not strictly necessary
alter table t1 add constraint t1_u1 unique (col1, col2);

alter table t1 add constraint t1_u2 unique (col1_col2_least, col1_col2_greatest);

insert into t1 (col1, col2) values (1, 2);

insert into t1 (col1, col2) values (2, 1);

-- ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCHEMA.T1_U2) violated

insert into t1 (col1, col2) values (2, 2);
```

Comment: This solution is better for me as it allows the constraint to be visible in my JPA code. Thx a lot. The @a_horse_with_no_name's solution works fine as well but didn't fit in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with an expression, but that cannot be used in a unique *constraint*, only with a unique *index*

```
create unique index unique_1 
   on mytable (least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2));
```

Comment: How can this be done with non-numbers???

Comment: @CollinFox: same solution